# Unfinished stubbing detected with JUnit4

Tags: kotlin, mockito, junit4

I am testing my authentication class using JUnit4 and Mockito. I wrote the following simple test class:

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class FirebaseAuthenticationDataSourceTest {
    @get:Rule
    val mockitoRule: MockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule()

    @get:Rule
    val instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @Mock
    var mockAuth: FirebaseAuth = mock()

    @Mock
    lateinit var mockSharedPref: SharedPreferences

    @InjectMocks
    lateinit var dataSource: FirebaseAuthenticationDataSource

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        // Inizializza i mock e il data source prima di ogni test
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this)
    }

    @Test
    fun `signIn success - should emit Success result with user data`() = runTest {
        // Mock il comportamento di FirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword
        val mockAuthResult = mock<AuthResult>()
        val mockFirebaseUser = mock<FirebaseUser> {
            on { email } doReturn "test@example.com"
            on { uid } doReturn "12345"
            on { displayName } doReturn "Test User"
        }

        // Utilizza when invece di whenever per mockAuth
        `when`(mockAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(any(), any())).thenReturn(mockTask(mockAuthResult)) //line 69
        `when`(mockAuthResult.user).thenReturn(mockFirebaseUser)

        // Esegui il metodo signIn del data source
        val signInFlow = dataSource.signIn("test@example.com", "password")

        // Ottieni i risultati dalla flow e verificali
        val results = signInFlow.toList()

        assertEquals(2, results.size)
        assertEquals(Result.Loading, results[0])
        assertEquals(Result.Success(User("test@example.com", "12345", "Test User")), results[1])
    }

    private fun <T> mockTask(result: T): Task<T> {
        val mockTask = mock<Task<T>>()
        whenever(mockTask.isSuccessful).thenReturn(true)
        whenever(mockTask.result).thenReturn(result)
        return mockTask
    }
}
```

Which tests the following method:

```
class FirebaseAuthenticationDataSource
@Inject
constructor(
    private val auth: FirebaseAuth,
    private val sharedPref: SharedPreferences
) : AuthDataSource {

    override fun signIn(email: String, password: String): Flow<Result<User>> = flow {
        emit(Result.Loading)
        try {
            val result = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).await()
            emit(
                Result.Success(
                    User(
                        result.user!!.email ?: "",
                        result.user!!.uid,
                        result.user!!.displayName ?: ""
                    )
                )
            )
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            emit(Result.Error(e))
        }
    }
}
```

The previous method must allow the user to log in using Firebase as the provider in this case.

But when I launch the test, I get this error:

```
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
-> at com.indisparte.loginfeature.data.datasource.FirebaseAuthenticationDataSourceTest$signIn success - should emit Success result with user data$1.invokeSuspend(FirebaseAuthenticationDataSourceTest.kt:69)

E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Hints:
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, which is not supported
 3. you are stubbing the behaviour of another mock inside before 'thenReturn' instruction is completed
```

I don't understand where the error is, searching the internet it would appear that I am grafting mocks but I don't understand where.

Comment: it says that the problem is in `FirebaseAuthenticationDataSourceTest.kt:69`. What is in line 69 in that file?

Comment: @GastónSchabas This ``when`(mockAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(any(), any())).thenReturn(mockTask(mockAuthResult))`

Answer (score 0):

When you are testing class you need to use @InejctMocks on him. @InjectMocks creates an instance of the class and injects the mocks that are created with the @Mock (or @Spy) annotations into this instance.
so replace this

```
    @Mock
    lateinit var dataSource: FirebaseAuthenticationDataSource
```

with this:

```
    @InjectMocks
    lateinit var dataSource: FirebaseAuthenticationDataSource
```

Comment: I updated the code but the error persists on line 69: `when(mockAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(any(), any())).thenReturn(mockTask(mockAuthResult))`